# Non commutative Non reduced ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring. $R$ may not be reduced and commutative. Is it true in general ring that if for any $a,b,c\in R$, we have $abc=bca=cab=0$ then it implies $acb=0$. We can prove this in case of reduced rings. But what if the ring is not reduced?

Comment: What is the proof for the case of reduced rings?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744038/reduced-ring-are-si

Comment: This link has the answer for this @RobArthan

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: What about $a = E_{11}$, $c = E_{12}$, $b = E_{22}$ in a matrix ring? Would be nice if there is a well-studied large class of rings where it does hold (Armendariz maybe..?) Why do you study these specific conditions @Chaudhary?

Comment: Thanks @Amateur_Algebraist. I am studying these type of rings.

Comment: I, for one, am still confused about the hypotheses you want. Are you insisting the ring isn't commutative, or allowing it? Something like $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ has that property on triples, and clearly isn't reduced.

Comment: Actually the rings in which $abc=0$ implies $acb=0$ are called symmetric. It is known fact that reduced rings are symmetric. I am trying to figure out the more strict class between reduced rings and symmetric rings.

Comment: @Chaudhary Why would you consider this _between_ symmetric rings and reduced rings?  You have reduced $\implies$ symmetric $\implies$ (your condition.)

Comment: How can I contact you @rschwieb for some discussion.

Comment: If we exchange further messages, you should get a "do not use comments for extended discussions" and it'll have a link to a chat room we can use.  I don't know how many it takes.

Comment: There is a chatroom link on your profile page also. Is it the same link you are talking about?

Comment: @Chaudhary I tried to find your chatroom link ("Start a chat with...") but couldn't find it. If you see mine you can give it a shot.

Comment: I am also unable to find your chatroom link.

Comment: @Chaudhary You don't see it on [this page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/37566/rschwieb)?

Comment: @Chaudhary Still curious what you were gonna ask